# file is locked by user while copying styles to opened document by VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, styles

I have an active document with updated styles. I have VBA code in it as well. I opened another document and try to copy styles from active-document to opened document. but it gives me an error "xxx.docx file is locked by ABC user". what should I do to prevent this message. maybe I am not opening it incorrectly.

```
    With wdApp
      .Visible = True
      
        While strFile <> ""
        If strFile = "By MBA.docm" Then GoTo NX
            
            'If IsWorkBookOpen(PathF & strFile) = False Then
                        
            On Error Resume Next
            Set dTarget = .Documents.Open(PathF & strFile)
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox strFile & vbCr & vbCr & "Name is not correct." & vbCr & "Processing next file...", vbOKOnly + vbInformation: GoTo NX
        
            'End If

       For Each S In dSource.Styles
       
            If S.Type = wdStyleTypeParagraph Then
                
                On Error Resume Next
' - - -- - > promt line  <- -- - - -- 
                Application.OrganizerCopy Source:=dSource.FullName, _
                  Destination:=dTarget.FullName, Name:=S.NameLocal, _
                  Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles
                  
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    On Error GoTo 0
                Else
                    J = J + 1
                End If
                
            End If
        Next S
    
        sTemp = "Copied " & J & " styles"
    
    MsgBox sTemp
    
'Header Footer Part
    dTarget.Sections.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
    
        For Each H In dSource.Sections.First.Headers
            dTarget.Sections(1).Headers(H.Index).Range.FormattedText = H.Range.FormattedText
            
        Next
        
        For Each H In dSource.Sections(2).Headers
            dTarget.Sections(2).Headers(H.Index).Range.FormattedText = H.Range.FormattedText
            
        Next
            
        For Each F In dSource.Sections.First.Footers
            dTarget.Sections(1).Footers(F.Index).Range.FormattedText = F.Range.FormattedText
            
        Next

        For Each F In dSource.Sections(2).Footers
            dTarget.Sections(2).Footers(F.Index).Range.FormattedText = F.Range.FormattedText
            
        Next
       
            
            With dTarget
                Cpro = Cpro + 1
                Application.StatusBar = Int((Cpro / CountDoc) * 100) & "% Completed --- (" & Cpro & "/" & CountDoc & ") Processing... File Name == " & dTarget
              
                'Close the document
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
                Set FSO = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                FSO.CopyFile PathF & strFile, TempFolder & strFile

            End With
            
          'Get the next document
NX:            strFile = Dir()
        Wend
        
        Set dTarget = Nothing
        .Quit
    End With
```

Comment: Is "ABC user" you?

Comment: yes! "ABC" its me. file is not opened already.

Comment: I would remove all of the the `On Error Resume Next` (the one in the loop only gets cancelled if an error occurred, meaning some other error could occur later in your code and wouldn't be caught...)   See what happens without that.